# I tried to make my first database and I got error

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

I just started learning MySql for Python on W3Schools. I copied the code that was given as an example and I run it in IDLE, but I got an error.

```py
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="myusername",
  passwd="mypassword"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE mydatabase")
```

Here is the full traceback:

```
  File "C:\Users\risto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 509, in open_connection
    self.sock.connect(sockaddr)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/risto/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/mysql1.py", line 6, in <module>
    passwd="mypassword"
  File "C:\Users\risto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\__init__.py", line 179, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\risto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\risto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py", line 716, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "C:\Users\risto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 206, in _open_connection
    self._socket.open_connection()
  File "C:\Users\risto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 512, in open_connection
    errno=2003, values=(self.get_address(), _strioerror(err)))
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it)
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: are you sure about installing sql correctly ? Also it might be you not set surname and pasword then try:

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user='root',
  passwd=''
)

Comment: try to connect using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`

Comment: I think I found the problem, it says that neither python nor visual studio is installed. I have them both installed. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: The error 
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
States that it's impossible to connect to the database. This error should only occur if 
a) Database is not running (try to restart it)
b) You have the wrong hostname. Try to ping it.
c) You firewall is blocking the traffic. Turn of the the firewall, including on domain level (you have to go into advanced to do that). Windows firewall is a total mess and block stuff even if it seems to be turned off.

Answer (score 0):

the service about MySQL is not running, or filtered by some firewall rule.

Check it out